# Parameter database MariaDB my.cnf

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb, database-performance, my.cnf

I pass an app (hotline for our customers) that runs on Java with a DB2 BDD (on an AS400 race beast) to a MariaDB BDD that runs on a Unix server.
I have a performances problem.
The new Unix server has two processors * 1 core and 5GB of RAM. I could negotiate 2 hearts more but hardly beyond.
The app can be solicited by 100 users / day, and 10-15 active users at the same time.
My main table has 20000 records (number of hotline tickets) but the dependent tables can reach some 150 000 records.
I use the InnoDB  engine,because I am obliged to keep the constraints of foreign keys.
I created the most logical indexes.
Each table has an average of 50 fields. (Decimal and varchar 10 or 20)
The problem is that I have queries with 5 views that use 4 tables each (see other views), which is very greedy with several tens of thousands of records per table. I can hardly modify these queries unless I completely rewrite the app. (I remind you that this is just a change of BDD).
Can anyone tell me if my.cnf setting is OK or not. I tuned in looking for info on the web but I'm not an expert.

```
# MariaDB database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this file to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#  
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc_messages_dir = /usr/share/mysql
lc_messages = en_US
skip-external-locking
lower_case_table_names = 1
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 10.10.64.51
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
max_connections     = 100
connect_timeout     = 5
wait_timeout        = 600
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_cache_size       = 128
#sort_buffer_size   = 4M
sort_buffer_size        = 8M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 16M
#tmp_table_size     = 32M
#max_heap_table_size    = 32M
#tmp_table_size          = 256M
tmp_table_size          = 512M
#max_heap_table_size     = 256M
max_heap_table_size     = 512M
#
# * MyISAM
#
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched. On error, make copy and try a repair.
myisam_recover_options = BACKUP
key_buffer_size     = 128M
#open-files-limit   = 2000
#table_open_cache   = 400
table_open_cache        = 600
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 512M
concurrent_insert   = 2
read_buffer_size    = 2M
#read_rnd_buffer_size   = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 2M
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
# Cache only tiny result sets, so we can fit more in the query cache.
#query_cache_limit      = 128K
query_cache_limit               = 512K
#query_cache_size       = 256M
query_cache_size                = 512M
#query_cache_type       = DEMAND
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error logging goes to syslog due to /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf.
#
# we do want to know about network errors and such
log_warnings        = 2
#
# Enable the slow query log to see queries with especially long duration
#slow_query_log[={0|1}]
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
long_query_time = 10
#log_slow_rate_limit    = 1000
log_slow_verbosity  = query_plan

#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#log_slow_admin_statements
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#report_host        = master1
#auto_increment_increment = 2
#auto_increment_offset  = 1
log_bin         = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin
log_bin_index       = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.index
# not fab for performance, but safer
#sync_binlog        = 1
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
# slaves
#relay_log      = /var/log/mysql/relay-bin
#relay_log_index    = /var/log/mysql/relay-bin.index
#relay_log_info_file    = /var/log/mysql/relay-bin.info
#log_slave_updates
#read_only
#
# If applications support it, this stricter sql_mode prevents some
# mistakes like inserting invalid dates etc.
#sql_mode       = NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,TRADITIONAL
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
default_storage_engine  = InnoDB
# you can't just change log file size, requires special procedure
#innodb_log_file_size   = 50M
#innodb_buffer_pool_size    = 256M
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 512M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 8M
innodb_file_per_table   = 1
innodb_open_files   = 400
innodb_io_capacity  = 400
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem

#
# * Galera-related settings
#
[galera]
# Mandatory settings
#wsrep_on=ON
#wsrep_provider=
#wsrep_cluster_address=
#binlog_format=row
#default_storage_engine=InnoDB
#innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
#
# Allow server to accept connections on all interfaces.
#
#bind-address=0.0.0.0
#
# Optional setting
#wsrep_slave_threads=1
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completion

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Best regards

Comment: Did you run any tests using different settings yourself?

Comment: Are your users suffering performance problems? Are you aware that MariaDB does not handle so-called *materialized views* out-of-the-box? Are you aware that MariaDB cannot use more than one index per table in a query, and therefore often benefits from well-chosen compound covering indexes?  Your best bet for optimization may be to investigate the *slow query log*, identify the slowest queries, and optimize them by adding appropriate indexes.

Comment: It's very cool that a port from DB2 / AS400 to MariaDB is working!

Comment: What is "BDD"?  What is a "heart"?

Answer (score 0):

Change these:

```
tmp_table_size = 50M
max_heap_table_size = 50M
query_cache_size = 50m
```

Answer (score 0):

@ Mickael : yeah I ran several other tests.
@ rick : BDD = database, heart is the core of the CPU.  Sorry for bad translation from French

@ Rick why are you setting these parameters to lower values ??